# how to hide drop down list in poymer-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer, dart-polymer, polymer-3.x

I need to hide dropdown-menu. i tried .hidden property but it is not working

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="firmChannelFilter" hidden="${(this._channelFilterVisibility)}" 
             class="small-padding" label="Channel Filter">
             <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" 
             .hidden="${(this._channelFilterVisibility)}" id="firmChannel"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `hidden` property as follows:

`hidden$="[[_channelFilterVisibility(valueThatChanges)]]"`

1. If you hide the `paper-dropdown-menu`, it will automatically hide the `paper-listbox` because it is a nested element.
2. If you are changing a non-polymer-specific attribute/property, you need to add a $ before the =, i.e. `class$="[[_colour(obj.Active)]]"` or `class$="[[_selectedColour(selectedFilter)]]"` or the hidden attribute.
3. You don't need the `this` quantifier - Polymer already knows and interprets anything you use between `[[]]` or `{{}}` as belonging to `this`.
4. You have to pass in a property to the function, otherwise it will only ever call once on page/element load. If you pass in a property that changes, i.e. a filter property, Polymer will call the function every single time that property value changes.
5. The attribute is `hidden`, not `.hidden` in the `paper-listbox`.
6. `{{}}` is used for two-way binding, normally used when you are interacting with something that displays and sets a value, such as your paper-listbox. `[[]]` is single-way binding, normally used when something is only taking in a value.

At the end of the day, your html code should look something like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="firmChannelFilter"
                     hidden$="[[_channelFilterVisibility(filterProperty)]]"
                     class="small-padding"
                     label="Channel Filter">
  <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content"
                 class="dropdown-content"
                 id="firmChannel"
                 selected="{{selectedIdString}}"
                 attr-for-selected="id">
    <paper-item id="A">Item A</paper-item>
    <paper-item id="B">Item B</paper-item>
    <paper-item id="C">Item C</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Briefly, this is a dropdown menu that has 3 items: Item A, Item B and Item C. When you select one of them it will set the value of `this.selectedIdString` to the string "A", "B", or "C". When the value of `this.filterProperty` changes, the function `this._channelFilterVisibility` will be called with the new value as the passed in parameter.